# JavaScript - Pushing a value on an array after clearing it keeps the old values

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm using JavaScript (prototype and ajax), PHP and MySQL to display some values from a database in textfields and a dropdown list, but I ran into a problem with JavaScript.

Every time a user clicks on an option in a list the values should update. These values are pushed in an array, but even after clearing it or setting its length to 0, the values get pushed to the end of how the array was before.

It all works fine the first time, but after that the array keeps on getting bigger and it adds more and more values to the dropdown list. Here's the code:

```
function artSelect(art){
//perform an Ajax request
var artRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

//If the output is returned successfully, add it in the document
artRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (artRequest.readyState==4) {
        //Get the text
        var text = artRequest.responseText;
        //Create an array
        var x = new Array();
        //Create a variable for storing the position of the last semicolon (the values are seperated by semicolons)
        var lastSemCol = 0;
        //Split the text by scanning for semicolons and put them in an array
        for (var i=0; i<text.length; i++) {
            //If the current char is ";"
            if (text[i] === ";") {
                //Create a substring of the chars between the last ; and current ;
                var value = text.substr(lastSemCol + 1, i-lastSemCol-1);
                //Add the value to the array
                Array.prototype.push(value);                
                lastSemCol = i;
            }
        }
        //Set the values in the document
        $("beschrijving").value = x[1];
        $("kleur").value = x[2];
        $("voorraad").value = x[3];
        $("prijs").value = x[4];
        $("srtc").value = x[5];
        //Set the departments
        for (var i=6; i < Array.prototype.size(x); i++) {
            var option = document.createElement("option");
            option.text = x[i];
            $("afd").add(option);
        }
        //Clear the array (no effect)
        x.clear();
        x.length = 0;
        x = new Array();
    }
};

artRequest.open("GET", "server.php?mode=getArtikel&artikel=" + selected.value.substr(0,7), true);
artRequest.send(null);
}
```

Comment: x.push(), not Array.prototype.push()...

Comment: Yep, that worked. Thanks! It's always the little things...